Silverstripe v4 URL issue
for some reason, my website URL is skipping back (pages in URL) to the index page
have a look please and click on any page
https://www.baybuckwheat.co.nz/
The URL will not display the page you clicked; it will show the domain name only!
so if I reload the page with F5 I go back to the index page
Not sure how to fix it
help, please
    "silverstripe/recipe-plugin": "^1.2",
    "silverstripe/recipe-cms": "~4.13.0@stable",


This is nothing to do with Silverstripe CMS - the problem is caused by some javascript on your front-end. You can verify this by disabling javascript in your browser and trying it again.
